# Why is containsAll with multi-dimensional lists always returning false?

Tags: kotlin, tic-tac-toe

There's a code where I am trying to create Tic-Tac-Toe.
When I tried to compare two lists to see if X or O won, I always got a false.
Why?
Is there another way to test for equality between lists?

```
fun main() {
    val userInput = readln()
    val gameBoard = mutableListOf(
        mutableListOf(userInput[0], userInput[1], userInput[2]),
        mutableListOf(userInput[3], userInput[4], userInput[5]),
        mutableListOf(userInput[6], userInput[7], userInput[8])
    )
    val decisions = listOf(
        listOf(0, 1, 2), listOf(3, 4, 5), listOf(6, 7, 8),
        listOf(0, 3, 6), listOf(1, 4, 7), listOf(2, 6, 8),
        listOf(0, 4, 8), listOf(2, 4, 6)
    )
    val whereXPlaced = MutableList(3) { (MutableList(3) { 0 }) }
    val whereOPlaced = MutableList(3) { (MutableList(3) { 0 }) }
    for (i in 0 until gameBoard.size) {
        for (j in 0 until gameBoard.size) {
            if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'X') {
                whereXPlaced[i][j] = j
            } else if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'O') {
                whereOPlaced[i][j] = j
            }
        }
    }
    if (decisions.containsAll(whereXPlaced)) {
        println("x win")
    } else if(decisions.containsAll(whereOPlaced)) {
        println("o win")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about the implementation itself, it's not quite right, let's assume the input is "XXX00O00O" , with your impl. you will get:

```
whereXPlaced = [[0,1,2],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
whereOPlaced = [[0,0,0],[0,0,2],[0,0,2]]
```

and `containsAll` checks if a list contains all the items in another list, for example:

```
val m1 = listOf(1,2,3,4,5)
val m2 = listOf(1,2)
m1.containsAll(m2) // true

// or using 2D lists
val m1 = listOf( listOf(1,2,3), listOf(4,5,6), listOf(7,8,9),)
val m2 = listOf( listOf(1,2,3), listOf(4,5,6),)
m1.containsAll(m2) // true
```

if you want to keep the same `decisions` list then you can use this:

```
fun main() {
  val userInput ="XXX--O--O"

  val gameBoard = mutableListOf(
     mutableListOf(userInput[0], userInput[1], userInput[2]),
     mutableListOf(userInput[3], userInput[4], userInput[5]),
     mutableListOf(userInput[6], userInput[7], userInput[8])
  )
  val decisions = listOf(
     listOf(0, 1, 2), listOf(3, 4, 5), listOf(6, 7, 8),
     listOf(0, 3, 6), listOf(1, 4, 7), listOf(2, 6, 8),
     listOf(0, 4, 8), listOf(2, 4, 6)
  )

  val whereXPlaced = mutableListOf<Int>()
  val whereOPlaced = mutableListOf<Int>()
  for (i in 0 until gameBoard.size) {
     for (j in 0 until gameBoard.size) {
        if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'X') {
          whereXPlaced.add((i*gameBoard.size)+j)
        } else if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'O') {
          whereOPlaced.add((i*gameBoard.size)+j)
        }
     }
  }

  if (decisions.contains(whereXPlaced)) {
     println("x win")
  } else if(decisions.contains(whereOPlaced)) {
     println("o win")
  }
}
```

note that we're using 1D lists for `whereXPlaced` and `whereXPlaced` because `decisions` list contains 1D lists, and we're using a simple `contains` , also `(i*gameBoard.size)+j` so if `i = 2` and `j = 0` then the flattened index is `(2*3)+0 == 6`

or if you want to keep the same `decisions` list and a 2D `whereXPlaced/whereOPlaced` then you can use something like this:

```
fun main() {
  val userInput = "xxx--o--o"
  val gameBoard = mutableListOf(
     mutableListOf(userInput[0], userInput[1], userInput[2]),
     mutableListOf(userInput[3], userInput[4], userInput[5]),
     mutableListOf(userInput[6], userInput[7], userInput[8])
  )
  val decisions = listOf(
     listOf(0, 1, 2), listOf(3, 4, 5), listOf(6, 7, 8),
     listOf(0, 3, 6), listOf(1, 4, 7), listOf(2, 6, 8),
     listOf(0, 4, 8), listOf(2, 4, 6)
  )
  val whereXPlaced = MutableList(3) { (MutableList(3) { false }) }
  val whereOPlaced = MutableList(3) { (MutableList(3) { false }) }
  for (i in 0 until gameBoard.size) {
     for (j in 0 until gameBoard.size) {
        if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'x') {
          whereXPlaced[i][j] = true
        } else if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'o') {
          whereOPlaced[i][j] = true
        }
     }
  }

  val x_indices = whereXPlaced.flatten().foldIndexed(mutableListOf<Int>()) { index, acc, b -> 
     if (b) acc.add(index) ; acc }
  val o_indices = whereOPlaced.flatten().foldIndexed(mutableListOf<Int>()) { index, acc, b ->
     if (b) acc.add(index) ; acc }


  if (decisions.contains(x_indices)) {
     println("x win")
  } else if(decisions.contains(o_indices)) {
     println("o win")
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you so much! I have all of the information I need to solve this problem.